# Applescript to javascript using node.js

Tags: node.js

I have an applescript that I would like to improve performance. Someone mentioned using node.js. I'm new to this and was wondering if the following is possible in node. I have a series of folders (say, Folder A, Folder B, etc.) and in these folders are subfolders named Main and Thumbnails. What my applescript does is pull all the files out of the Main folder into the root folder (Folder A, Folder B), then deletes the Main folder and the Thumbnails folder (files in Thumbnails are not needed).

Is this something that can be done in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this something that can be done in node.js?

Yes. But it is also something that can be done even simpler with a shell script.

But technically the answer to your question is: Yes.

Some APIs that you will most likely need to use:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
- https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Some modules that can help you simplify concurrency:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/async
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird

Comment: Yeah, I would also go for a shell script, Node.js seems overkill (and probably has a steeper learning curve, too).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to convert it to node.js with your suggestions.